# Gmail ignoring Reply-To field in my Magento emails

Tags: email

My company uses Google Apps for Business. We've created a contact form on our site that captures users' comments on the checkout page. I wanted to set the Reply-To field as the user's email address (to avoid servers marking it as a spoofed email address if I use the To field). Gmail doesn't seem to recognize my Reply-To field. Here is a snippet from the original email source with fake data.

```
"...
12.34.56.78 as permitted sender) client-ip=12.34.56.78;
Reply-To: myemailaddress@domain.com
To: =?utf-1?BTWF0dCBTd1FuY1hpZQ==?=
..."
```

I've compared it to other email sources and my formatting seems correct. I can post the extension code if necessary but I'm really just curious if this is proper formatting. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't realize this but apparently if you "own" the email address in the *From* field, it will ignore the *Reply-To* and default to your *From* address.

http://www.backwardcompatible.net/152-GMail-ignores-Reply-to-header-SOLVED

I used a different address than one associated with my Google Apps for Business and it worked.

Comment: This used to work but seems not to work anymore